# TextView can't set drawableLeft(or Top,Right,Bottom) with Shape drawable?

Tags: android, textview, drawable, shapes

I defined a shape drawable ,it's a line.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >
<stroke android:color="#f00" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

and then I set this shape in TextView's drawableBottom,but it didn't work.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/shape_line"
    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
    android:text="Hello World" />
```

why and how can let it work?

Comment: Did you try setting an `android:height` attribute for stroke in your shape?

Comment: stroke don't have 'android:height'  attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this!!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<size
    android:height="1dp"
    android:width="500dp" />

<solid android:color="#f00" />

</shape>
```

Comment: No, the key is `<size>`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just add a separate view below the textview. Since you just want a line add a View and set the height to 2dp and the background color to #f00

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/shape_line"
    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
    android:text="Hello World" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    //set your custom color
</View>
```

Comment: I know this solution,but don't want to use it. Thanks!